# C# apply a different file to the same variable

Tags: c#, audio

I am trying to create a series of buttons, each play a sound. This sound is retrieved from an OpenFileDialog function. However, I have encountered the issue of one sound being assigned to all of the buttons. I know why this occurring, but I am unsure of how to resolve the issue. Basically, I began by assigning the same algorithms to each button:

```
openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;

        }
```

And:

```
soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
        soundPlayer.Play();
```

Unfortunately, this was extremely ugly and so I decided to put each algorithm in to a method and just call the methods to their respective buttons. Like so:

```
public void openDialog()
    {
        openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;

        }
    }

private void button27_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openDialog();
    }

public void playDialog()
    {
        soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
        soundPlayer.Play();
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playDialog();
    }
```

However, because `openDialog()` calls the same variable which receives the file name, each of the buttons calling `openDialog()` is using the same variable and so playing the same sound.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the fileName "part" of the Button. You can do it by either:

- Using the Tag property of a button and cast to string when retrieving
- Create a subclass of a Button called SoundButton and add FileName property of type string

Make a pick.

For example, using a Tag:

```
public void playDialog(string fileName)
{
    soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(fileName);
    soundPlayer.Play();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    playDialog((sender as Button).Tag as string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of sounds and then play it in a loop one by one:

Creating the list:

```
List<string> soundsList = new List<string>();
```

Adding to the list:

```
sounds.Add(openFileDialog.FileName);
```

Playing sounds:

```
foreach(string sound in soundsList)
{
  soundPlayer = new SoundPlayer(sound);
  soundPlayer.Play();
}
```

My answer of course is assuming you keep an order of first adding all the sounds you want and then playing them all. You should of course also need to add validation to check that the user has given you a correct sound to add to the list.

EDIT:
After reading your comment, you can also add a sound to `Tag` property of the button. Then when you want to play a sound of a specific button, you can just play whatever is inside that property of the button.

For example you can override the Click event like this:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string soundFile = (sender as Button).Tag as string;
   playDialog(soundFile);
}
```

This way all sounds are a "part" of the button

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what I am looking for. I want each button to have their own sound, not to be played in series.

Comment: You can then use the "Tag" property to store a sound there for each button. Then you can just play whatever is there in that property